# How to format numbers to two decimals in a f string expression?

Tags: python

I am trying to make this program that asks a user for their grades and displays their grades with 2 decimals. - ex. if they got a 10/15 on their Assignment it would show Assignment 1: 66.66%

In my code, it seems I am having trouble converting the numbers calculated to two decimals.

```
    print("Please enter your grade on the following pieces of work:")
a1 = int(input("Assignment 1 (/15):"))
a2 = int(input("Assignment 2 (/20):"))
a3 = int(input("Assignment 3 (/25):"))
a4 = int(input("Assignment 4 (/20):"))
a5 = int(input("Assignment 5 (/30):"))
t = int(input("Tutorials (/10):"))
m = int(input("Midterm (/30):"))
fe = int(input("Final Exam (/50):"))


print("Here are your grades: ")

print(f"Assignment 1:{a1/15*100}%")
print(f"Assignment 2:{a2/20*100}%")
print(f"Assignment 3:{a3/25*100}%")
print(f"Assignment 4:{a4/20*100}%")
print(f"Assignment 5:{a5/30*100}%")
print(f"Tutorials:   {t/10*100}%")
print(f"Midterm:     {m/30*100}%")
print(f"Final Exam:  {fe/50*100}%")
```

These answers give the whole decimal answer, for example instead of showing 66.66% it would show 66.666667%. How would I make this into 66.66%?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also how would I take these answers and create the average percentage?

Comment: `{a1/15*100:.2f}` should do the trick for the first one. so basically add `:.2f` to get to decimals

Comment: Do you know how I would take these answers and calculate the final average?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to denote that you want the formatting in two decimal points. - You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
{your_calculation:.2%}
```

The `.2` in this case denotes that you want the formatting in two decimal points. If you want to increase or decrease the decimal points you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks, this really helped. I was wondering if you know how I would find the average using these answers? I understand the math but the coding part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: How would you do it in math? :) (it will teach you more than myself just giving you the answer)

Comment: If you don't want a percent sign and you just want to show a number with two decimals places in an f-string, you can use `:.2f`.

Answer (score 3):

python supports percent as formatting option:

```
a3 = 7
print(f"Assignment 3:  {a3/25:.2%}")  # 'Assignment 3:  28.00%'
```

note that there is no need to divide by 100 when using `%` as format specifier.

search form `percent` in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). more information on formatting can be obtained here: https://pyformat.info/.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should ask your second question as a separate question, but one implementation would be to create a pandas dataframe.

```
 import pandas as pd
 last_assignment_number = 5
 assignments = ['Assignment {}'.format(i) for i in range(1,last_assignment_number+1)]+
                 ['Tutorials','Midterm','Final Exam']
 scores = pd.DataFrame(index=assignments+['Total'],
                 columns=['score','maximum','percentage'])
 maximum_scores = [15,20,25,20,30,10,30,50]
 scores['maximum'] = maximum_scores+[sum(maximum_scores)]
 for assignment in assignments:
      scores.loc[assignment,'score']=int(input("{} (/{}):").format(assignment,scores.loc[assignment,'maximum'])
 scores.loc['Total','score']=scores.loc[assignments,'score'].sum()
 scores['percentage']=(scores['score']/scores['maximum']).apply(lambda x:f"{x:.2%}")
```