# Changing single decimal float to two decimal places, ie 56.0 to 56.00

Tags: python

I'm soving some practice questions on Hackerrank.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/finding-the-percentage/problem

my response is:

```
print('{0:.2f}'.format(sum(student_marks[query_name])/3))
```

but essential you can imagine it as:

```
print('{0:.2f}'.format(56.0))
```

which gives the correct answer but I am just wondering if that is an efficient way of converting any single decimal point number to two decimal points.

Comment: 56.0 and 56.00 is the same number. (Try `56.0==56.00`.) You are talking about two different visual representations.

Comment: @DYZ The expected output is 56.00, whereas 56.0 gives an failed response.

Comment: That's what I said: You are talking about two different visual representations of the same number. Your code works and it is correct. If you want to get a review, [there's another website for it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Your solution is better then what you can scrunge up without converting to string first. If you use `f"{56.0:.2f}"` or `.format()` or even `'%.2f' % 56.0` is kinda irrelevant - I would use the f.string version

Comment: You're not "converting" the number (or rounding it), you're merely formatting it. It's still the exact same underlying number.

Comment: One of many near-duplicates: [How to format numbers to two decimals in a f string expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481711/how-to-format-numbers-to-two-decimals-in-a-f-string-expression)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
print(format(56.0, ".2f"))
```

If you want to increase it more, you can increase it by doing `.3f`,`.4f`,`.5f` so on and so forth.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Little easier way using old-style string formatting:

```
print('%.2f'%56.0)
```

To your actual code:

```
print('%.2f'%sum(student_marks[query_name])/3))
```

Output:

```
56.00
```

Comment: Why not `print("56.00")`, then?

Comment: @DYZ OP wants a coding way.

Comment: Define "coding way." If you have a constant, the easiest way to print it is just to print it.